# Django-Graphene: No module named 'graphql_jwt'

Tags: python, django, graphql

I'm trying to implement authentication with Django and GraphQL/graphene

I've run into the error `No module named 'graphql_jwt'.` and the solutions I've found don't seem to work

## Reproducing

The code is available here:
https://github.com/altear/hello-GraphQL/tree/7ae1229b29f144f0f511d1b1a86edba36053dd86

```
git clone https://github.com/altear/hello-GraphQL.git
git checkout 7ae1229b29f144f0f511d1b1a86edba36053dd86
```

It uses docker-compose, so you should be able to run it with just `docker-compose up -d --build`

The error is immediately visible if you go to http://localhost:8000

## What I've Tried

Other posts that have this error don't seem to be applicable:

- one mentions having another folder named "graphql" in the python path. But I use docker so my environment should be clean (there's nothing like that in the project dir)
- another mentions not having installed graphql. However, it's in my requirements.txt and it worked before I tried adding authentication

Comment: You're importing `graphql_jwt` but it's not present in your requirements (usually as `django-graphql-jwt`) as far as I can see? It's not imported by any of your dependencies either, I think? Why do you expect it to be present?

Comment: The issues I've been reading through post solutions like `pip install graphene_django` which suggests it's packaged with graphene (also the graphql docs don't mention any additional installs when talking about using it in authentication/authorization)

Comment: I think you're right, but I can't find what package to install other than the ones I have (or maybe what version). The first page of google results don't seem to mention it

Comment: `django-graphql-jwt` ?

Comment: That... worked. I feel dumb, I spent an hour trying solutions from git issues. If you post an answer I'll accept it, there should be a more direct way of finding this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [graphql-jwt module for Django is available](https://github.com/flavors/django-graphql-jwt) as `django-graphql-jwt`.

You have to add this as an explicit dependency in your project unless it's a transitive dependency by one of the other projects (which according to the requirements.txt in your project and the setup.py's I looked briefly at, it isn't).